# How Does System.Drawing.Color Struct Initialize Colors?

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing.color

I need to create a type that contains a few methods and a long list of constants.

After a little research, I think I'd like to take the same approach taken by the `System.Drawing.Color` struct. However, looking at the source for this structure (generated from meta data) gives me something like the following.

```
public byte A { get; }
public static Color AliceBlue { get; }
public static Color AntiqueWhite { get; }
public static Color Aqua { get; }
public static Color Aquamarine { get; }
public static Color Azure { get; }
public byte B { get; }
// ...
```

Can anyone explain to me how the static Color values (which are the same type as the containing struct) ever get initialized? I must be missing something.

Comment: I don't think they'd expose every single implementation detail. In any case my first guess is that each static property simply returns a `new Color(...)` with the appropriate ARGB values.

Comment: I see. So you're saying they don't get initialized. Rather, they are generated when requested. If so, this approach doesn't sound quite a clean as I was originally thinking.

Comment: Assuming Color is mutable (I haven't actually used it), you would want new instances of it every time, no?

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: these are static properties, they are initialized only once, not when requested

Comment: @xixonia: If you look at the `A` (alpha) and `B` (blue) properties you'll see that they're readonly - it probably isn't mutable.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Well, my question is how are they initialized. However, BoltClock has a good point. They don't need to be initialized. Instead, the getter can simple return the appropriate value when requested.

Comment: @BoltClock, yeah, I noticed that, but I wasn't sure if there were other mutable fields in the  "// ..." portion. You can always use reflector to see what's going on. Or just get the private fields using reflection. If it's got private static "mAliceBlue", etc. chances are they're only instantiated once.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood @BrokenGlass: Yup, remember structs are value types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the `Color` class with Reflector you will see:

```
public static Color AliceBlue
{
    get
    {
        return new Color(KnownColor.AliceBlue);
    }
}
```

That confirms that a new `Color` object is returned every time.

Comment: +1 for buying reflector, so I didn't have to. Another day... another dollar saved.

Comment: @xixonia: Turns out when Reflector forces you to update when you get the "do you want to update" dialog (and nothing else works) apparently get the last free version - just tried it earlier and it works after reading this thread: http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=13238

Comment: @BrokenGlass, I'll have to try this when I get to a computer with a pre-pay4it version. I downloaded a bit late here :/

Comment: Well, now I'm not sure where the `Color` constructor is that accepts one argument (I don't see it), but this would seem to answer the original question.

Comment: @Jonathan - it's marked as internal so you can't use that one: `internal Color(KnownColor knownColor);` - but you can use `Color.FromKnownColor()`

Answer (score 2):

Using the .NET Reflector (derived code below), we can see that a new color struct is created each time the static Color property (ex: AliceBlue) is called.  Microsoft probably implemented it this way to ensure immutable values for this property.

```
public static Color AliceBlue
{
    get
    {
        return new Color(KnownColor.AliceBlue);
    }
}
```

An internal constructor is called and passes an enum value (KnownColor.AliceBlue) to the contstructor.  The Color structure stores this enum and sets a flag/state that it is a known color.

```
internal Color(KnownColor knownColor)
{
    this.value = 0L;
    this.state = StateKnownColorValid;
    this.name = null;
    this.knownColor = (short) knownColor;
}
```

Further, from analyzing the .NET Reflector code, when you try to get a value out of the `Color` structure (such as the `R` property), the property does a search on a lookup table (i.e. private static array) using the knownColor enum and returns an `Int64` representing all of the color information.  From there it does some bit manipulation (bitwise AND, bit shifts, etc.) to come up with the byte representing the `R` (or `G` or `B`, etc.) value.